# randn con variables de Matlab a Julia

Tags: random, matlab, julia

Estoy intentando traspasar un codigo de Matlab a Julia, sin embargo tengo un error cuando intento ejecutar A= randn... (m y n se ejecutan sin problemas)

```
m = round(10*exp(log(100)*rand())) 
n = round(10*exp(log(100)*rand())) 
A = round(sigma*(randn(m,n)));
```

El error: MethodError: no method matching randn(::Float64, ::Float64)

Answer (score 0):

En Julia, `round` únicamente redondea a tantos dígitos como indiques. Ejemplo:

```
julia> round(10.57, digits = 1)
10.6

julia> round(10.57, digits = 0)
11.0
```

Pero, nótese que:

```
julia> round(10.57, digits = 0) isa Integer
false
```

Y la función `randn` necesita que las dimensiones sean enteros, ya que ¿qué dimensión tiene una matriz de (10.0x5)?

La solución al problema pasa simplemente por convertirlo a un tipo entero:

```
julia> m = Int(round((10*exp(log(100)*rand()))))
196

julia> n = Int(round((10*exp(log(100)*rand()))))
80
julia> randn(m, n)
196×80 Matrix{Float64}:
 -0.338527     0.919091  -0.805756   1.21764     -0.840262    …   0.483696   -1.5522     -2.11284    -1.12987
 -1.48902     -0.763076   0.559108   0.808948    -0.712493        0.204387    0.170378    0.563179    0.896811
  1.35562     -0.533283  -0.881877  -1.77778      1.28062        -0.440008    0.390854   -0.279679   -0.416463
 -0.356996     1.40992   -0.359547  -0.373926    -0.0277324       1.27025     1.86382     1.30097    -0.369661
  0.00537268  -0.759788   2.30765   -0.197545    -0.145871       -0.0967599  -0.060285    0.0477333  -0.704547
  0.179037    -0.260163  -1.52097    1.47664      0.648531    …   0.60301    -1.50275    -0.569118    0.199974
 -1.42254      1.688     -0.973713   0.671575    -0.124514       -0.200776   -1.57319     1.9454      0.297579
  0.338746    -1.16853   -0.681051  -1.78057      1.33378        -0.800471   -0.861991    0.64073    -0.890785
 -0.895684     1.19908   -1.17241    1.19836      1.83653         0.904639   -1.48884    -1.86271    -0.536287
 -0.565051    -1.06757   -1.2103     1.9103       0.584925       -0.109526    2.16488     1.184      -0.50895
 -1.51457     -0.364947   0.41839   -1.0451       1.46676     …  -1.33555    -0.846842    0.79902     0.573643
  0.145649    -1.32283    1.25309   -1.42731     -0.0869235       0.198298    0.0510992   0.676475   -0.0690357
  0.0348139    0.722626  -1.26237    0.00239882   1.5516         -1.10318     1.23797     0.385364   -1.70347
  ⋮                                                           ⋱
  0.0288347   -0.396485  -0.188293  -1.4994      -0.994217        0.568184    0.110274    0.0956363  -0.0884397
 -0.100542    -0.856825   0.861107   0.577723     1.04868     …  -0.0469476  -1.42746     0.490992   -0.115437
  0.283136     0.745315   1.23983   -0.513409     0.32863        -0.975982    0.0125279  -0.420864   -0.211027
 -0.911426     0.909032   0.39178    0.121405     1.23239        -1.52523     0.21694     0.783335    0.135549
 -1.02273     -0.628547   0.88929   -0.518107     1.00298         0.296201   -0.0674339  -1.62125    -1.02959
 -0.93656      1.38738   -0.751345   2.19642      0.642252        1.52325    -0.0641779  -0.397013    0.43865
  0.15975      0.263151  -1.00277   -0.288378     2.53049     …   0.618799   -0.919645   -0.87429     0.200413
  0.637895     0.279829   1.11791    1.44518     -0.169004       -0.734972   -1.46977    -1.02315    -0.144916
 -0.68204      0.191561  -0.145104   0.132979    -0.714469       -1.59593    -0.863564    0.298642   -0.0330418
  1.08035      0.640044  -0.833827  -0.356928     1.0794          1.39448     1.79005    -0.389522    0.0940427
  1.59312      0.012752   0.245805  -0.152936     0.00590619     -0.779995   -0.0698571  -1.25332     1.80952
 -0.187718    -0.189629  -0.834244  -0.974346    -1.67586     …  -0.211797    1.1483      0.973253   -2.11287
```